# OutOfMemory Exception Occurs in Android App

Tags: android

I have a problem that I am receiving data from JSON response, there are many images in data also. There are large amount of data as more than 100. Therefore it returns OutOfmemory exception when I try to load it in LazyAdapter or when try to call method as NotifydatasetChanged of LazyAdapter. Please suggest any solution regarding the same.

**Code:**

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                    ResearchList.this, "Research List       ",
                    "Please wait...   ", true);

            final Handler handler = new Handler() {

                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    // System.out.println("The id after Save:"+id.get(0).toString());

                    // catagory.addAll(keyword_vector1);
                    linear_Category_Child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    linear_Category_Child_Child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //tv_Child_Header.setText("Volvo");
                    tv_CategoryChildHeader.setText(from);
                    setHeaderImage(tv_CategoryChildHeader.getText().toString());

                    if(coll.getDisplayNames().size()!=0)
                    {
                        adapter = new CategoryListLazyAdapter(
                                ResearchList.this);
                        lvCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
                        Utility util = new Utility();
                        util.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lvCategory);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /*lvCategory.invalidate();
                        lvCategory.setAdapter(null);*/
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(ResearchList.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Attention!");
                        builder.setMessage("No Data Available for the Particular Search.");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    }
                                });

                        builder.create().show();
                    }
                    /*Utility util = new Utility();
                    util.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lvCategory);*/
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            };

            final Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    try {
                        String sortEncode = URLEncoder.encode("mpg");
                        String filterEncode = URLEncoder.encode(filter);
                        String clientEncode = URLEncoder.encode("10030812");
                        String fromEncode = URLEncoder.encode(from);
                        String toEncode = URLEncoder.encode(to);
                        String catUrl = "/v1/vehicles/get-make-models.json?sort="
                                + sortEncode
                                + "&filter="
                                + filterEncode
                                + "&client-id="
                                + clientEncode
                                + "&from="
                                + fromEncode;
                        genSig = new GetSignature(catUrl, "acura");
                        try {
                            signature = genSig.getUrlFromString();
                        } catch (InvalidKeyException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        // jsonString =
                        // getJsonSring("http://api.highgearmedia.com/v1/vehicles/get-models.json?make=acura&client-id=10030812&signature=LWQbdAlJVxlXZ1VO2mfqAA==");
                        // String signatureEncode =
                        // URLEncoder.encode(signature);
                        String urlEncode = URLEncoder.encode(catUrl
                                + "&signature=" + signature);
                        jsonString = getJsonSring("http://apibeta.highgearmedia.com"
                                + catUrl + "&signature=" + signature);
                        System.out.println("The json category:===>"
                                + jsonString);
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JsonParse json = new JsonParse(jsonString);
                    json.parseCat();
                    LIST_SIZE = coll.getDisplayNames().size();
                    for (int i = 0; i <= BATCH_SIZE; i++) {
                        // countriesSub.add(COUNTRIES[i]);
                        countriesSubCat.add(coll.getDisplayNames().get(i));
                        imagesSubCat.add(coll.getImages().get(i));
                        YearSubCat1.add(coll.getYears().get(i));
                        YearSubCat2.add(coll.getYears().get(i + 1));
                        mpgSubCat1.add(coll.getMpg().get(i));
                        mpgSubCat2.add(coll.getMpg().get(i + 1));
                        priceSubCat1.add(coll.getPrice().get(i));
                        priceSubCat2.add(coll.getPrice().get(i + 1));
                        ratingSubCat1.add(coll.getRating().get(i));
                        ratingSubCat2.add(coll.getRating().get(i + 1));
                    }
                    setLastOffset(BATCH_SIZE);
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                }

            };
            checkUpdate.start();
```

**GetJSonString Method(Error Place):**

```
public String getJsonSring(String api_url) throws URISyntaxException,
            ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            URL url = new URL(api_url);
            URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(), url.getPath(),
                    url.getQuery(), null);
            request.setURI(uri);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream ips = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips, "UTF-8"));




            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String s;
            while (true) {
                s = buf.readLine();
                if (s == null || s.length() == 0)
                    break;
                sb.append(s);

            }
            buf.close();
            ips.close();
            return sb.toString();

        }

        finally {
            // any cleanup code...
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are parsing the entire JSON feed at once, which is too large to be held in memory. Use a JSON **stream** parser such as [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) (which is also pretty fast) which allows you to parse the JSON objects as you pull the feed from the server.

As you parse the images dump them to disk to free up memory and load them again as you see fit.